# How can I add a custom wrapper to NGX-Formly with references the field model?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-formly

I'm trying to implement a wrapper for NGX-Formly fields which features a button that calls a handler function passing a reference to the wrapped field's model. How can I inject this reference and pass it to the handler function (which e.g. opens a popup or similar)?

My objective is to create a drag&drop form builder.

Following [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjleoz) I have implemented a wrapper like that:

```
<div class="formly-wrapper">
 <label>{{ to.label }}</label>
  <button (click)="myHandlerFunction()">Edit</button>
  <ng-container #fieldComponent></ng-container>
</div>
```

How can I get the field definition or at least a reference to the wrapped field?

Comment: What have you tried? Please read [ask] and [example].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying back and forth I found that you can pass **field** in the wrapper like so:

```
<button (click)="myHandlerFunction(field)">Edit</button>
```

This gives you the complete FieldConfig whereas **to** is just an alias for TemplateOptions.